# Why isn't this MP3 playing in the Video Sequence Editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I am trying to add an audio file to one image. I have tried repeatedly but the audio file doesn't play. I have used tutorials that suggest it should just play right away when I run the file but nothing. The originals are an MP3 and a PNG file.

I have the codec set as Quicktime with H.246 and AAC audio codec.

Please advise!

[image]

Comment: Hi. In future (I have already corrected it) please upload images using the built-in uploader. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Audio should be heard on playback. Select the audio strip and scroll down in the audio strip properties. Enable ***Draw Waveform*** to ensure that Blender actually reads audio. Can you see a waveform? Have you checked other audio output sockets?

Comment: I figured out how to draw the waveform. I am not sure what other audio sockets are and I still get no sound no matter what I try.